# Remove left/right padding on header

Tags: css, header, padding

I have a website at http://www.vjpp.nl and want to remove the padding on both sides of the header, content and footer.

In the header I found this:

```
.fusion-header {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
```

When I set both to 0px it doesn't change anything. Basically what I need is that the button and logo are aligned with the menu bar without any padding. Same goes for the content and footer (social media logos). I can't find a solution, does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also change

```
            .fusion-header-wrapper .fusion-row {
            padding-left: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            /* max-width: 1000px; */
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `max-width` of the element `.fusion-header-wrapper .fusion-row` inside the header, which is centered and thus has a gap to the header. Remove this `max-width` and it will work.